# Why is my src switching breaking at random using jquery and left/right keyup events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to build a photogallery, using jquery, but I have it mostly working, but for some reason, the src does not get properly changed at times (most of the time it does), even if the active thumb class is correct and swapped, I tried everything, but there is a bug that eludes me

HTML

```
<div class="container gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 bigImgArea">
            <img src="" class="fullImg">
        </div><!-- end bigImgArea -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 thumbnails">
            <img src="IMG_8943_thumb.jpg" class="thumb active">
            <img src="22_thumb.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="IMG_8943_thumb.jpg" class="thumb">
        </div><!-- end thumbnails --> 
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end gallery -->
```

scripts

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var next = $(".active").next().attr("src");
    var prev = $(".active").attr("src");
    $(".thumb").hover(function(){
             $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
        });

        $(".thumb").mousedown(function (){       
        var regex = $(this).attr("src");
         regex = regex.replace("_thumb", ""); //images and thumbnails have same filename, extept thumbs have _thumb at the end
          $(".fullImg").hide().attr("src",regex).fadeIn(600); 
        });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){
 // go right from active thumb
        if (e.keyCode == 39){
            var regex = next.replace("_thumb", "");
            $(".fullImg").hide().attr("src",regex).fadeIn(600);                                                
            next = $(".active").next().attr("src");
            prev = $(".active").attr("src");
            curr = $(".active");
            $(".active").next().addClass("active");
            curr.removeClass("active");
            regex= "";
 // go left
        } else if(e.keyCode == 37){
            var regex = prev.replace("_thumb", "");
            $(".fullImg").hide().attr("src",regex).fadeIn(600);
            curr = $(".active");
            $(".active").prev().addClass("active")         
            curr.removeClass("active");
            next = $(".active").next().attr("src");
            prev = $(".active").attr("src");
            regex ="";                
        }            
    });
    console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: From a quick look I would say that your order of execution is not correct. In the keyup event you first assign new values to next prev and curr and only then assign a new `active` element. Maybe this is how you wanted it, but it seems coounter-intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and set up a fiddle. From what I see, you would be better off swapping the `<img/>`

Either clone() the next/previous one and replace the 'active' one with it.

Switching the src  attribute is always 'risky' and very poorly supported.
From what I remembered FF had a bug with it, and you ahd to first change to '#' and then switch to the new image source.

Again, I would recommend you to switch the whole `<img/>` tag